# BigDecimal division, rounding and sums

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am working with a BigDecimal value that represents a currency amount. I need to split this amount into 6 rates with the first 5 rates being rounded up to 5, the 6th rate will be the rest.

```
BigDecimal numberOfRates = new BigDecimal("6");
BigDecimal currencyAmount = new BigDecimal("650.30");
BigDecimal rate = currencyAmount.divide(numberOfRates);
rate = //rate rounded up to closest multiple of 5
BigDecimal lastRate = currencyAmount.subtract(rate.multiply(new BigDecimal("5"));
```

My 2 questions are:

- How do I round to the closest multiple of 5 (or any other int)?
- Will the 6 rates summed up always give the original currencyAmount or are there issues with precision due to the division?

(This is a simplified example, I do realize that the last rate could be negative with this setup.)

*** Updated Question ***

Expected result with the example is:

- Rates 1-5: 110.00
- Rate 6: 100.30
  And in this case: 5*110.00 + 100.30 = 650.30

By using the indicated approaches will it always be the case that the sum of all rates equals the initial amount?

Comment: In this example what are your expected results ?

Comment: Adam's answer below should work fine for you based on what is described. The only thing I'd say is that the requirements you make two separate statements (1) "the first 5 rates being rounded up to 5" and (2) "round to the closest multiple of 5 (or any other int)?". If your requirement is the second then it is the exact answer, otherwise if your requirement is actually the first then you would change the code to RoundingMode.UP instead of RoundingMode.HAFL_UP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the standard approach of divide, round, multiply

```
private static BigDecimal round(BigDecimal input, int multiple) {
    return input.divide(new BigDecimal(multiple))
            .setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING)
            .multiply(new BigDecimal(multiple));
}

for (double i = 0; i < 10; i += 0.9) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%.1f => %s", i, round(new BigDecimal(i), 5)));
}
```

Output

```
0.0 => 0
0.9 => 5
1.8 => 5
2.7 => 5
3.6 => 5
4.5 => 5
5.4 => 10
6.3 => 10
7.2 => 10
8.1 => 10
9.0 => 10
9.9 => 10
```

Comment: Shouldn't rounding mode be up based on requirements? Actually, requirements are unclear, one place says up to 5 and the other says nearest 5.

Comment: This won't give a multiple of 5 for the intermediate values

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but as my output shows 5 and 10 are multiples of 5??

Comment: I understood as nearest multiple of 5

Comment: I agree, this should work fine. The only question is which way rounding should be as requirements make two inconsistent statements.

Comment: Yea, it actually says both. So could be either. It is just a change to RoundingMode anyway

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and thank you for the answer. I always want to round up. So from 0.0 => 0, 0.1 => 5, 5.0 => 5, 5.4 => 10. How do you correctly write that down? Isn't round up to closest multiple of 5 correct?

Comment: HALF_UP means 1.5 goes to 2, HALF_DOWN means 1.5 goes to 1 it still goes to nearest. You need CEILING. I've updated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding of the requirements, i would do the following for calculating `rate` :

```
BigDecimal rate = currencyAmount
            .divide(new BigDecimal(numberOfRates * 5), RoundingMode.UP)
            .setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP) 
            .multiply(new BigDecimal(5));
```